# None permission for chromedriver.exe in colab

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run the webdriver resource in the selenium module (python) in Chrome for the google colab. Firstval I have problems to parse the chromedriver.exe file in the command (selenium.webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver.exe')), overcome that I found the continuos failure of none permission to run the chromedriver.exe, and the version is ok, who knows what possibly is wrong?

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions.

Comment: Did you add chromedriver.exe location in the System PATH variable ? (when you open a command line window and type chromedriver.exe does it find it ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by installing the chromium webdriver and adjusting some options such that it does not crash in google colab:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://www.webite-url.com")
```